# Can I delete the BIOSUPDATE partition (with ASrock z87)?

Tags: partitioning, bios, uefi, storage

I found a partition on my secondary (!) storage drive, **not the system** storage drive:

[image: BIOSUPDATE partition]

As you can see it is in the way of easy repartitioning. I have an ASRock Z87 Mainboard, used the *update Bios via Internet* feature in the past.

What consequences will it have if I delete it? (Google and the Manual were no help)

Comment: You likely would have to recreate it if you wanted to update your BIOS firmware in the future.  Check the manual for the software you used for more information.

Comment: The manual **for the mainboard** doesn't provide any information about that.

Comment: It might force future bios updates to be applied while in Windows, which can be hazardous, I would leave the partition if you ever want to upgrade the bios in the future. Use good partitioning software to do what you need, no good reason to delete the 512mb partition.